# R fill up matrix according to conditions

Tags: r, matrix, conditional-statements, fill

There is a matrix 5x5, where the row sums and column sums are given

```
mat1<-matrix(0,ncol = 5, nrow = 5)
colnames(mat1) <- c("A","B","C","D","E")
rownames(mat1) <- c(1:5)
mat1<-rbind(mat1, Sum = 2)
mat1<-cbind(mat1, Sum = c(1,3,2,3,1,""))
View(mat1)
```

The row  and column sums mean, that not more cells than the sum can be filled up with 1.
The matrix has to be filled up that the conditions (row sum and column sum of every matrix element) are fulfilled as far as possible.
But the cells of every row must be filled up within the define interval:

```
mat2[1,]<-c(1,1,0,0,0)
mat2[2,]<-c(1,1,1,1,0)
mat2[3,]<-c(0,1,1,0,0)
mat2[4,]<-c(0,1,1,1,1)
mat2[5,]<-c(0,0,0,1,1)
mat2<-rbind(mat2, Sum = 2)
mat2<-cbind(mat2, Sum = c(1,3,2,3,1,"")) 
View(mat2)
```

As a result, I want to receive the following matrix:

[image]

Put it otherwise,the matrix can be filled up with only within intervals, which in the following matrix are red fulfilled:

[image]

Thank You in advance!

Answer (score 3):

There is more than one solution to your problem. See this code that makes use of the [Patefield's algorithm](https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/2346669.pdf?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) (each time your run it you have a different solution, here I give 3 different examples):

```
mat1 <- r2dtable(n=1, r=c(1,3,2,3,1), c=rep(2,5))[[1]]

colnames(mat1) <- c("A","B","C","D","E")
rownames(mat1) <- c(1:5)
mat1 <- rbind(mat1, Sum = 2)
mat1 <- cbind(mat1, Sum = c(1,3,2,3,1,""))

mat1
```

> ```
>      A   B   C   D   E   Sum
> 1   "0" "1" "0" "0" "0" "1"
> 2   "1" "0" "0" "1" "1" "3"
> 3   "0" "0" "1" "1" "0" "2"
> 4   "0" "1" "1" "0" "1" "3"
> 5   "1" "0" "0" "0" "0" "1"
> Sum "2" "2" "2" "2" "2" ""
> ```

---

> ```
>      A   B   C   D   E   Sum
> 1   "0" "0" "0" "0" "1" "1"
> 2   "2" "0" "1" "0" "0" "3"
> 3   "0" "0" "1" "1" "0" "2"
> 4   "0" "1" "0" "1" "1" "3"
> 5   "0" "1" "0" "0" "0" "1"
> Sum "2" "2" "2" "2" "2" ""
> ```

---

> ```
>      A   B   C   D   E   Sum
> 1   "0" "0" "0" "1" "0" "1"
> 2   "0" "1" "1" "0" "1" "3"
> 3   "0" "1" "0" "0" "1" "2"
> 4   "1" "0" "1" "1" "0" "3"
> 5   "1" "0" "0" "0" "0" "1"
> Sum "2" "2" "2" "2" "2" ""
> ```

Comment: Thanks for Your answer!

I have fogotten to say that the cells of every row must be filled up within the define interval, which are in mat2 with 1 filld up. And every row has to be filled up in order from up to down and from left to right.

Comment: I am not sure I correctly understand your question. But as you seem to have many conditions, the easiest solution would probably be to use for loops.